# Update UI within .map() when condition changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array `posts`, and a separate array `favourites`. I want the UI to display "Favourited: [Yes or No]" depending on if `favourites` includes the value from `posts`.

The problem is when I add to `favourites` the UI never updates.

I made a minimal example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-useeffect-playground-forked-n645c?file=/src/index.js
I'm new to react and I feel like this should be simple - I did tons of research but I can't get it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
function App() {
  return <TestPage />;
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);


export default function TestPage() {
  const posts = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState(["1"]);

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div
          style={{
            "background-color": "lightblue",
            width: "300px",
            height: "60px",
            margin: "5px",
            "font-size": "20px"
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            favourites.push(post);
            setFavourites(favourites);
            alert("Added " + post + " to favourites");
          }}
        >
          {post}
          <br />
          Favourited: {favourites.includes(post) ? <>Yes</> : <>No</>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
favourites.push(post);
setFavourites(favourites);
```

React states need to be immutable. `.push` will modify the existing array, and then when you set state react does a `===` comparison between the old and new states, sees that they're the same array, and so it skips rendering. Instead, you need to create a new array:

```
setFavourites([...favourites, post]);
```

It's also a good idea to use the function version of setFavorites when your new state is based on the old. This makes sure you have the latest value of the state and so eliminates the possibility a category of bugs.

```
setFavourites(prev => {
  return [...prev, post];
});
```

Comment: Thankyou. I was trying hard to fix the react code meanwhile I ignored the basic JavaScript. I am stupid.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my non-example code which isn't here I thought I made a new array then did `.push()` and `setFavourites` from that, but I think it was just a reference to the old array so it didn't work. Can't believe I spent hours on this.. thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
onClick={() => {
    setFavourites(favourites.concat([post]));
    alert("Added " + post + " to favourites");
}}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I was trying hard to fix the react code meanwhile I ignored the basic JavaScript. I am stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always create a new object, and push that to the state.

If you push an object to state that is already in the state then React will ignore it, even if the object content has changed (it doesn't do a deep contents comparison).

This code will work:

```js
onClick={() => {
    const newFavs = [favourites]; // create copy of original object
    newFavs.push(post);
    setFavourites(newFavs);
    alert("Added " + post + " to favourites");
}}
```